# $e^{\mathrm{Re}\,z}$ not analytic in complex plane

Tags: functions, exponential-function, analyticity

In my textbook I found a text where it says that $e^z$ (z is a complex number) is analytic everywhere.

But $e^x=e^{\mathrm{Re}\,z}$ is not.

How can I prove that about $e^x$ and what is the  difference?

Comment: Is $e^x$ used for $e^{\operatorname{Re} z}$ here?

Comment: @DanielFischer my bad. yes it's$ e^{\operatorname{Re} z}$

Comment: Okay. Then you can see in many different ways that it isn't analytic. I guess you're at the very start of the course/book, so probably the expected argument is via the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Just compute the partial derivatives and verify they don't satisfy the CR equations.

Comment: To clarify: you're asking why $e^z$ is analytic but $e^{Re(z)}$ isn't? (Bringing "$x$" into things is really just making this more messy.)

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot in the implicit notation here let us be explicit:

The map 
$$\exp : \begin{cases}\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \\
z \mapsto  e^z \end{cases} $$ 
is analytic; for example as it is given by the powerseries $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{n}}{n!}$

The map 
$$\exp \circ \Re : \begin{cases}\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C} \\
z \mapsto  e^{\Re z} \end{cases} $$ 
is not analytic, for example as the Cauchy-Riemann equations do not hold, (they do not even hold at a single point). It is of course a power series in $\Re z$, yet *not* in $z$ which is what is relevant.

Yet  the map 
$$\exp  : \begin{cases}\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C} \\
x \mapsto  e^x \end{cases} $$ 
is of course still (real) analytic. It is the restriction of the first to the reals, that happens to be equal to the second there.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the Cauchy-Riemann Equations to check the differentiability
Let $f(z)=e^x=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$
Check the condition $u_x=v_y,u_y=-v_x$

Comment: Yea that's clears things up! Thank you